# Editing my own stuff get me suspended?

Tags: support, editing, suspensions

I just got taken off a 1 year suspension for the second time. I don't want to do anything that will get me another 1 year suspension.

I saw many things I wanted to edit on my own stuff while I was suspended. Should I pace my edits or am I safe to edit everything with in scope of coarse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you were suspended last time around for posting low-quality questions (which are a problem because they create work and annoyance for other members of the site) and making scores of edits that didn't substantially improve the posts being edited but did clog the active lists with questions that folks had already seen (which *also* creates work and annoyance for others).

So... If you want to avoid being suspended again, don't do anything that creates work and annoyance for other users:

- Put more thought and research into your questions before posting them - if you can't formulate a clear, well-researched question, sit on it for a bit until you have the time to flesh it out.
- Put more thought into your edits before submitting them - if you're not sure the edit you're about to submit makes a significant difference in the quality or content of the post you're editing, don't submit it until you have an edit that does.

Comment: What things can I do to my own stuff that does not create work for others?

Comment: @Muze It's simple: don't do things to your own (old) stuff. Water under the bridge, fresh new start. Do things better this time, and forget about the past.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform that is an issue I have with the system. Although I am off suspension it isn't a fresh start.  The first time I got suspended I was allowed to make far more mistakes that the second time and the second suspension happen with in a month. A year is really to long for minor offenses many that it may be . Instead of a question ban I got a full suspension. I am going to try hard not to get suspended again, but it would be nice to have a real fresh start.

Comment: I described in detail how you should behave above, @muze. It's your responsibility to follow that advice, no one else's.

Comment: @Shog9 You been very helpful . I do have much to learn. Do you not agree that 1 year should be given to minor offenses? Do you think its fine the way it is?

Comment: I think most people learn faster when they're not trying to blame others for their ignorance.

Comment: Hi Muze, welcome back. Two things FWIW that you might consider, 1. write out your questions by hand first, I don't ask questions myself that much now, but I used to do that, and 2. I think you had some questions that showed real  curiosity and interest for physics,  (I love curosity more than most things), but you rushed them. Don't rush them :) I think you asked about a ring around Earth like Jupiter's......I always remember that question, anyway best of luck this time.